# Using Excel to determine a specific date based on user input

Tags: excel, date, formulas

What I am trying to accomplish is: I have a cell that allows input of any given date.

The user can put any date in cell A1.

Cell B1 will automatically match the month from a-1 to a pre-designated month/date/year from a list.

For instance, if I input `01/29/2014` or any date in January into cell A1, cell b1 will be able to find the only date I've designated on the list to be `01/14/2014`.

And any date put in for Jan, will result in cell B1 finding `01/14/2014` every time from the list. Same thing with Feb and other months. Depending on what I've designated to be the answer for the month based on input in A1.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking, since you have not provided any of your own code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I am game for some guesswork. Since you mention month I assume there are only 12 possibilities for the B1 result, that I have show in D1:E12 :

[image]

The formula in B1 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(MONTH(A1),D:E,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

perfect this worked, this is exactly what i was looking for. now my next question.

you have this working exactly like i need it for A1.

Now lets say IF A1's date is greater than B1, C1 would auto populate the following months date(from the same dates listed in D and E)?

A1 would read:01/29/2014 B1 would populate: 01/14/2014, and so since a1 is greater than b1, Cell C1 would populate 2/15/2014

And more so, what if i needed the list to go into the following year?